# After the closure of Google Reader, Feedly will still work? or need more data?

Tags: google-reader, feedly

Feedly for data collection, require each user's permissions for Google Account.
After the closure of Google Reader, Feedly will still work? or need more data?

Comment: @pnuts There is a close reason for that :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Feedly blog](http://blog.feedly.com/2013/03/14/google-reader/) it will work after the Google Reader shutdown:

> Google announced today that they will be shutting down Google Reader.
>   This is something we have been expecting for some time: We have been
>   working on a project called Normandy which is a feedly clone of the
>   Google Reader API – running on Google App Engine. When Google Reader
>   shuts down, feedly will seamlessly transition to the Normandy back
>   end. So if you are a Google Reader user and using feedly, you are
>   covered: the transition will be seamless.